# How do I test the frontend of my django/react app?

Tags: django, reactjs

I have a Django/React app that I'd like to integrate some pre-deployment testing into. I can build tests in django for python specific stuff, but how would I go about building some robust testing for my frontend? Do I need to build some Selenium functions that test my react app in the browser? Or is there a more efficient way to do this in react?

Answer (score 0):

-Always run yarn build after you've updated your front-end.

While developing, you have to run the react server and Django server separately to make
use of the built-in hot-reload of these servers.

```
 $ yarn build
 $ poetry shell
 $ python manage.py runserver.
```

This is the command I use to test the frontend of my Django/react app.

Comment: I do! `yarn build` is a part of my compiling process. I'm more referring to application functionality. Things like forms, charts, and tables. Testing those to ensure they operate as designed.

Comment: Then I highly recommend that you try Jest and Enzyme for all your application functionality. This is such an efficient way in React.

Comment: Thank you @Nqobile Ndlovu! Been using React for 2 years now and never heard of these. 